# How do you check if a string is not equal to an object?

Tags: java, string

I ave a code where I want to use != sign. But since I am using String, How do I not equals Sign. Hers is my code. So I want all this statement not to equal to each other so it can print Tie Game.

```
    if (Array[0] == Array[currentPlayer] &&  Array [1] == 
    Array[currentPlayer] && !Array [2] == Array[currentPlayer])
```

The above code is when everything equals to each other. But I want this statements not to equal each other.

Keep in mind that I have not used Int or Char, I am using String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For string inequality, negate a call to the equals method using the `!`:

```
String x = "ABC";
String y = "XYZ";
if(!x.equals(y)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

`!` can be used to negate ANY boolean expression, and `String.equals` returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
if (!Array[0].equals(Array[currentPlayer]) &&  !Array[1].equals(Array[currentPlayer])  
    && Array[2].equals(Array[currentPlayer]))
```

Use `equals()` if you want case sensitive match meaning it will look at case of string as well when matching.
If you want case insensitive matching you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method in place of `equals()`